# Fetch API PUT did not find the pipeline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I tried update some data on my JSON using Fetch API PUT, but it said 404 not found in console.
When I tested it in POSTMAN it was OK (200). 
I suspecious on the fetch there is some thing wrong.

Here the Fetch code.

```
fetch(`/api/customers/21111`, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        Accept: "aplication/json",
        "Content-Type": "aplication/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        Variabel: "coba"
      })
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(
        "There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ",
        error.message
      );
    });
    };
```

Here the Express code.

```
app.put("/api/customers/:id", (req, res) => {
const customer = customers.find(c => c.id === parseInt(req.params.id));
if (!customer) res.status(404).send("Id is not found");

const { error } = validateCourse(req.body);
if (error) {
  res.status(404).send(error.details[0].message);
  return;
}

customer.Variabel = req.body.Variabel;
res.send(customer);
});
function validateCourse(customer) {
const schema = {
  Variabel: Joi.string()
    .min(3)
    .required()
};
return Joi.validate(customer, schema);
}
```

Comment: Accept: "aplication/json", should be "Accept": "application/json" and same spelling error in Content-Type line also .. first fix them and check

Comment: hahahaha... Yes, you are correct... Thanks for help...